# How can I create child elements radially around parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a center point that I want to add child elements to dynamically when a button is pressed. I need to create them at random degrees and ranges from the parent element (center). I am running into a few issues here:

1. I can't seem to append more than one element to the parent. When I view the DOM I see only one div appended.
2. When I change the rotation of the parent element it changes the position of all child elements. Is there a better way to position these children radially from the parent?
3. When I change the translation of the child element it affects all children. I have tried creating a new class .newDust for initial positioning with the intent on changing the class to .dust for the following logic and to disconnect it from the parent. Before I go through with this maybe a better answer to issue #2 will solve this problem.

Here is the HTML for my problem. I have a test "dust" element in place to see what happens when I create new elements and modify the center.

```js
// Setup variables

const createDust = document.getElementById("createDust");
const center = document.getElementById("center");
let newDust = document.createElement("div");
    newDust.className = "newDust";
let dust = document.createElement("div");
    dust.className = "dust";



let randomDegree;
let randomRange;

// Random degree generator

function randomizeDegree() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
}

// Random range generator


// Event listeners

createDust.addEventListener("click", () => {
    randomDegree = randomizeDegree();
    center.style.transform = `rotate(${randomDegree}deg)`;
    center.appendChild(newDust);
    newDust.style.position = 'absolute';


});
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #3c3c3b;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#center {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #62bbc1;
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dust {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #735cdd;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(200px);
}

.newDust {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #735cdd;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(200px);
}
```

```html
<div id="playArea">
    <div id="center">
        <div class="dust">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="createDust" type="button">CREATE DUST</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `newDust` should be created inside the event listener function. Otherwise, you're just appending the same old `newDust` every time.

Answer (score 3):

Use SVG with a `rotate` transform.

```js
/* generate a random integer greater than or equal to zero and less than limit */ 
const random = (limit) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit)
}

document.getElementById('createDust').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const c = `<circle cx="${random(76)}" cy="0" r="5" fill="hsl(251, ${random(101)}%, 61%)" transform="rotate(${random(360)})"/>`
  document.querySelector('svg').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', c)
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3c3c3b;
  font-family: Arial;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 0.2);
}

.center {
  fill: #62bbc1;
}

.edge {
  stroke: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.2);
  fill: none;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-85 -85 170 170">
  <circle class="edge" cx="0" cy="0" r="75"/>
  <circle class="center" cx="0" cy="0" r="5"/>
</svg>
<button id="createDust" type="button">CREATE DUST</button>
```

Comment: This seems to creat new particles always at the same distance from the Center.

Comment: @AHaworth good point, it appears that I didn’t read the question thoroughly. I have updated my code to correct that.

Comment: @BrettDonald thank you so much for your input. I made some minor adjustments to your code and it does pretty much what I want. I could not get the rotation to work properly, but just creating a point randomly within the svg bounds works for me. Maybe later I'll play around with that rotation trick to get the overall boundary a circle rather than a square.